# value of steps per epoch passed to keras fit generator function

Tags: keras, classification, generator

What is the need for setting `steps_per_epoch` value when calling the function fit_generator() when ideally it should be `number of total  samples/ batch size`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Keras' generators are infinite.

Because of this, Keras cannot know by itself how many batches the generators should yield to complete one epoch.

When you have a static number of samples, it makes perfect sense to use `samples//batch_size` for one epoch. But you may want to use a generator that performs random data augmentation for instance. And because of the random process, you will never have two identical training epochs. There isn't then a clear limit.

So, these parameters in `fit_generator` allow you to control the yields per epoch as you wish, although in standard cases you'll probably keep to the most obvious option: `samples//batch_size`.

Comment: should be `samples // batch_size` i believe

Comment: This answer created more questions in my mind :'|, first time to use generators

Answer (score 3):

Without data augmentation, the number of samples is static as Daniel mentioned.
Then, the number of samples for training is steps_per_epoch * batch size.

By using **ImageDataGenerator** in Keras, we make additional training data for data augmentation. Therefore, the number of samples for training can be set by yourself.
If you want two times training data, just set steps_per_epoch as (original sample size *2)/batch_size.

Answer (score 0):

This is the safest one.

```
steps_per_epoch = len(train_generator).
```

If you have 1300 images and batch size of 64, if you set `steps_per_epoch = 1300//64`, it will result in 20 steps per epoch, ignoring some image. By setting `steps_per_epoch = len(train_generator)`, you ensure all 1300 images are used during each epoch, including handling the case where the last batch might be smaller than the specified batch size due to division remainder.